# How can I apply a combining diacritic to a string in bash

Tags: bash, unicode, diacritics

I want to apply a combining diacritic (unicode) to a sequence of chars, not only one character.

I've come up with

```
var="world"
echo hello $var$'\u030A'
```

but this applies the diacritic to `d` only. How can I achieve that its applied to `world`?

Comment: You have to insert it after each character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
warp () {  # I misspelled "wrap" but now I don't want to change it (-:
    case "$1" in '') ;;
     *) echo "${1:0:1}"$'\u030A'"$(warp "${1:1}")";;
    esac
}
```

Comment: I suppose the recursion on the empty string is a bit of a wart, but adding a special case in the middle `?) echo "$1"'$\u030A';;` also seems a bit clunky; you cannot remove the case for the empty string, still.